# no applicable method for 'offspring' applied to an object of class "phylo"

Tags: r, ggtree, r-future

I think my issue is actually with `future` and exporting methods rather than `tidytree`, but if someone could explain to me what is actually happening and how I should be writing my code to avoid this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

I am using `tidytree` to do some phylogenetic analyses. The function `offspring` works fine when I use `lapply`, but throws the following error when I use `future_lapply`:

```
Error in UseMethod("offspring") : 
  no applicable method for 'offspring' applied to an object of class "phylo"
```

Reproducible example:

```
library(ape)
library(tidytree)
library(future.apply)

tree <- rtree(4)
lapply(5:7, function(x) offspring(tree,x, tiponly=TRUE))
future_lapply(5:7, function(x) tidytree::offspring(tree,x, tiponly=TRUE))
```

And corresponding output:

```
> lapply(5:7, function(x) offspring(tree,x, tiponly=TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] 1 4 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 2 3

> future_lapply(5:7, function(x) tidytree::offspring(tree,x, tiponly=TRUE))
Error in UseMethod("offspring") : 
  no applicable method for 'offspring' applied to an object of class "phylo"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this error also using `lapply()`;

```
library(ape)
library(tidytree)
tree <- rtree(4)
y <- lapply(5:7, FUN = function(x) offspring(tree, x, tiponly = TRUE))
#> Error in UseMethod("offspring") : 
#>   no applicable method for 'offspring' applied to an object of class "phylo"
```

And, also without `lapply()`;

```
library(ape)
library(tidytree)
tree <- rtree(4)
y <- offspring(tree, 5L, tiponly = TRUE)
#> Error in UseMethod("offspring") : 
#>  no applicable method for 'offspring' applied to an object of class "phylo"
```

This happens because `tree` is of class `phylo`:

```
class(tree)
#> [1] "phylo"
```

but **tidytree** does not provide any S3 methods for this class;

```
methods("offspring")
#> [1] offspring.tbl_tree*
#> see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

Looking at the example in `?tidytree::offspring`, it looks like you forgot:

```
tree <- as_tibble(tree)
```

Adding that makes it work, including with **future.apply**.

EDIT: Added the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I also came about this error, and i figured out it is about version of tidytree.
change **tidytree 0.4.5** to **tidytree 0.4.2**
change **ggtree 3.8.2** to  **ggtree 3.8.0**